# Enable logging of metro/tube

Tags: java, web-services, debugging, java-metro-framework

I need to enable logging of the raw data captured during webservice calls/requests (using Metro WS 2.0).

I have tried to enable the two following properties, but they give no result at all to the logging:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.TransportTubeFactory", "true");
```

The following gives the wanted effect but with every entry logged 8 times:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.metro.soap.dump", "true");
```

With every entry duplicated 8 times the log gets very cluttered and very timeconsuming to follow. How can I achieve tracing of the webservice calls/requests without having everything dumped in a duplicated manner?

Comment: Are you using log4j or what? Can you give details on the environment?

Comment: I am deploying the application on a Glassfish 2.1 app-server, and using the standard java.util.logging.Logger for logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem which I resolved by:

[Metro : Printing / dumping out the contents of a SOAP packet](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2010/01/metro-printing-dumping-out-contents-of.html).

Essentially, it uses the "MessageDumpingFeature". You find this in the Glassfish \lib directory in the webservices-rt.jar file.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I managed to get expected behaviour using your approach, thanks!